# Redux Saga - shouldn't a generator yield?

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I'm a bit confused regarding the behaviour of Saga:

```
export function* workerSaga() {
 const result = yield call(api.getData);
 yield put(action(result));
}
```

Given the concept of generators, i thought the generator should "exit the function" after each team it encounters a `yield`?
So how come if i call `workSaga()` it executes both `yields`s?

Comment: Calling a generator function does not execute its body immediately. An iterator object for the function is returned instead. When the iterator's `next()` method is called, the generator function's body is executed until the first `yield` expression

Comment: So in this case, why do both `yield`s run when i call the saga?

Comment: How did you call it?

Comment: `yield all ([
takeLatest(SOME_ACTION, workerSaga)
])
`